# How to Run Selenium Tests in Jenkins For C#

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please help me with easy steps on how to run the selenium WebDriver scripts (written in C# in Visual Studio Communities unit testing) in Jenkins and get results?

I went through some youtube videos, but could not get correct/exact steps that works for me. So, want to start afresh with someone's help.

Regards,
Alok

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags you select, so you don't select completely wrong or irrelevant tags. Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), retake [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Answer (score 1):

1)Install Nuit on build machine 
2)and in jenkins execute batch
3)all other dependency that code requires

in batch excute  command /shell  in jenkins config. depending on build machine OS

> path to nuit.exe *.dll

Comment: @Alok Agarwal can you please cat you vote  click on upper arrow beside answer . so that others be benefited

Comment: sure I will do.